# Mostrar solo los elementos que quiero al cargar la pagina y desaparecer los demás?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

ya lo realizo  pero dando click necesito que pase al cargar la pagina, les comparto el código

necesito que me muestre solo los div que tengan la calse home, lo  que pasa es que al iniciar me muestra todos los div, y necesito  que me muestre unicamente los de la clase home.

```
 var categories = $('nav .categories-container');
if (categories.length) {
  categories.pushpin({ top: categories.offset().top });
  var $links = categories.find('li');
  $links.each(function() {
    var $link = $(this);
    $link.on('click', function() {
      $links.removeClass('active');
      $link.addClass('active');
      var hash = $link.find('a').first()[0].hash.substr(1);
      var $galleryItems = $('.gallery .gallery-item');


      $galleryItems.stop().addClass('gallery-filter').fadeIn(100);


      if (hash !== 'all') {
        var $galleryFilteredOut = $galleryItems.not('.' + hash).not('.all');
        $galleryFilteredOut.removeClass('gallery-filter').hide();
      }else{
        var $galleryFilteredOut = $galleryItems.not('.' + hash).not('.home');
        $galleryFilteredOut.removeClass('gallery-filter').hide();
      }

      // transition layout
      $masonry.masonry({
        transitionDuration: '.3s'
      });
      // only animate on layout
      $masonry.one( 'layoutComplete', function( event, items ) {
        $masonry.masonry({
          transitionDuration: 0
        });
      });
      setTimeout(function() {

      $masonry.masonry('layout');
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo utilizas para ejecutar la función al iniciar la página

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //  tu codigo aqui
});
```

Comment: Si eso lo se, pero lo que no logro hacer es que ponga los de la clase home al cargar la pagina, solo al dar click